# "Advances in the past have inspired expectations that have not been met."

Tags: present-perfect

> Advances in the past have inspired expectations that have not been met.

Does this sentence only mean that 'inspiring expectations' has been made after 'advances in the past'? Because if 'inspiring expectations' had been made as 'advances in the past' was made, I think the simple past tense(just 'inspired') should have been used. I would really appreciate your help if you give me a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

"Inspired" is not an adjective but the main verb of the sentence, which is in the present perfect.

That is, there were advances, as a consequence of which, people were inspired to expect certain things that have not come to pass.